# PHP - Use Active_Page to show active page for navigation in include for two or more categories

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

I am using Active_Page to display what page I am on because my nav is in a include, But I have a multi-level nav and would like to have both highlighted as active, if I was on the Print.php page, I would like the "What We Do" tab highlighted aslong with the "Print" tab which is within the "What We Do" Tab.

---

Nav Include

---

```
              <li>
                <a href="#" id="<?php if (ACTIVE_PAGE == "What We Do") echo "active"; ?>">What We Do</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                       <a href="index.html#modal">Portfolios</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="solportfolios.php" id="<?php if (ACTIVE_PAGE == "Port-Solicitors") echo "active"; ?>">Solicitors</a></li>
                      <li><a href="esportfolios.php" id="<?php if (ACTIVE_PAGE == "Port-Estate-Agents") echo "active"; ?>">Estate Agents</a></li>
                      <li><a href="miscportfolios.php" id="<?php if (ACTIVE_PAGE == "Port-Additional") echo "active"; ?>">Additional</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="print.php" id="<?php if (ACTIVE_PAGE == "Print") echo "active"; ?>">Print</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="web.php" id="<?php if (ACTIVE_PAGE == "Web") echo "active"; ?>">Web Design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="services.php" id="<?php if (ACTIVE_PAGE == "Additional Services") echo "active"; ?>">Additional Services</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

---

Active Main Page

---

```
<?php
          define ('ACTIVE_PAGE',"Port-Estate-Agents");
          define ('ACTIVE_PAGE',"What We Do");
          include ('inc/nav.inc.php');   
      ?>
```

---

also tried..

---

```
  <?php
          define ('ACTIVE_PAGE',"Port-Estate-Agents","What We Do");
          include ('inc/nav.inc.php'); 


    ?>
```

---

and

---

```
<?php
          define ('ACTIVE_PAGE',"Port-Estate-Agents, What We Do");
          include ('inc/nav.inc.php'); 


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your nav is always only two levels deep you can just use two constants for it. Something along the line of ACTIVE_LEVEL1 and ACTIVE_LEVEL2.

```
<?php
      define ('ACTIVE_LEVEL1',"Port-Estate-Agents");
      define ('ACTIVE_LEVEL2',"What We Do");
      include ('inc/nav.inc.php');   
  ?>
```

It's not the nicest of all solutions though. Especially if you plan to add a third, fourth, fifth, ... level. If you plan to do so, you should model your navigation structure as a tree. This can with nested arrays or a full blown database based tree. Instead of checking if the page is active directly, you would call a method that checks if the page givven is part of the way from the root of the tree to your currently active page.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to PHP and this was the only solution that I could find at the time. I think the highest Level I would have is about three. so the Active_Level solution should work fine for this. I am instead to learn more about the other solutions you have mentioned tho.